# Local C# WPF application with cloud database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, cloud

I have a c# WPF application which I want to install locally on several computers. I would like to run the database in the cloud on a server from Ionos. Does anyone already have experience with this? Especially with a secure connection via vpn?
If so, does anyone have an example of what the connection string looks like here?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString = "Server=your_server_ip,1293;Database=your_database_name;User Id=your_username;Password=your_password;";
```

also check server firewall settings on IONOS should allow incoming connections through the VPN.